# How do I increase size of views depending on screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, constraints

I've been using Xcode for a while now and I like to use storyboards, but since the introduction of wider screens I am struggling to understand how to achieve the layout I desire.

EXAMPLE 1;

For example, let's say I am using a storyboard which is 320x580, across the top of the screen I have 6 UIButtons, each is 40x40 and evenly spaced.

What I want to achieve is the ability for the buttons to increase in size as the screen that displays them gets wider.

I have tried using all sorts of constraints in different ways to absolutely no effect.

EXAMPLE 2;

I have a UITableview with a cell 320 wide. I drop a UIView in there which covers the entire cell. 
I pin leading space, trailing space, top and bottom, but if I display it on a wider screen it is always 320 wide even though I don't have the width pinned at all!

How do I use auto layout and constraints? It seemed so much easier in Xcode 5.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Example 1:

If you want the buttons to get wider, you should make constraints to the edges and between each of the buttons, and make all of those spacing constraints the same size (or at least all the ones between the buttons). If you then set all the buttons to have the same size, but no fixed size, they will be equally spaced, and get bigger on a wider screen.

Example 2:

I don't know what you did here, because that should have worked, assuming the the table view itself was pinned to the sides of its superview.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the constraint equal to width  as superView.

```
var widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(widthConstraint);
```

You can give the constraint equal to height  as superView.

```
        var heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint);
```

You can change the multiplier value to change the widht and height constraint as ur requirment